# Is it UB to re-use an object's storage without destroying it first?

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++11

Given non-POD type `T`:

```
auto p = new T();
::new (p) T();
/* ... */
delete p;
```

This is UB, right?

Clearly I'm not directly leaking the memory allocated for that first `T` (and if it has no indirect members then I'm not leaking anything at all), but it never got destructed, which seems to me to be a great candidate for spontaneous annihilation of galaxies populated by sentient cat-like beings.

<sub>Thanks to [@Xeo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/500104/xeo) for, um, "inspiring" this question in the C++ Lounge.</sub>

Comment: "Clearly I'm not leaking any memory" - `T` itself is not leaked, but certainly any resources held by the object are leaked since it is not properly destroyed.

Comment: @Arne: You mean because "or if a delete-expression (5.3.5) is not used to release the storage" would be triggered? I admit it's not obvious but my interpretation is that this means the storage of the original object. Then, releasing the re-used storage at a later date would not effect the passage.

Comment: He means "undefined behaviour" I think.

Comment: @Arne: The storage of the first object becomes storage for the second (`[C++11: 3.8/7]`). You can absolutely release it thereafter.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It rather depends.

> `[C++11: 3.8/1]:` **The lifetime of an object of type `T` ends when:**
>
> - if `T` is a class type with a non-trivial destructor (12.4), the destructor call starts, or
> - **the storage which the object occupies is reused or released**.

Clearly, this is a case of re-use.

And:

> `[C++11: 3.8/4]:` **A program may end the lifetime of any object by reusing the storage which the object occupies** or by explicitly calling the destructor for an object of a class type with a non-trivial destructor. **For an object of a class type with a non-trivial destructor, the program is not required to call the destructor explicitly** before the storage which the object occupies is reused or released; **however, if there is no explicit call to the destructor or if a *delete-expression* (5.3.5) is not used to release the storage, the destructor shall not be implicitly called and any program that depends on the side effects produced by the destructor has undefined behavior.**

So, even for a non-POD type `T`, it's valid *iff* nothing in your program actually relied on what the destructor was doing.

It's a bit airy-fairy, but it does potentially allow what you're doing.

---

Note that this leniency does *not* extend to some only slightly more bizarre cases:

> `[C++11: 3.8/9]`: Creating a new object at the storage location that a const object with static, thread, or automatic storage duration occupies or, at the storage location that such a const object used to occupy before its lifetime ended results in undefined behavior

Comment: I don't think your interpretation of 3.8/1 is allowed: the second bullet is not providing an alternative mechanism to end the lifetime of *any* object, it describes when the lifetime ends for objects that are *not* of a class type with a non-trivial destructor. I do admit the standard would typically have an "otherwise" on the final bullet to make that distinction clear, I think it was unintentionally omitted here.

Comment: @Casey: I interpret the first bullet point as being conditional on that, and the second bullet point as being universally applicable. The standard has a habit of using the term "otherwise", otherwise. You make a valid point, though -- perhaps this isn't as clear as I'd hoped.

Comment: @Casey: I think the first sentence of `3.8/4` supports me, with its structure and use of the word "any".

Comment: To make it 100% correct, I think one should add the (somewhat obvious) clause _"...and p is reassigned or never again used thereafter"_ after _"if nothing in your program actually relied on what the destructor was doing"_. Since the object's lifetime has factually ended, the pointer to the object is now an invalid pointer.

Comment: @Damon: A pointer with the same value clearly now points to a new, valid object.

Comment: @Damon: `[C++11: 3.8/7]:` If, after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused or
released, a new object is created at the storage location which the original object occupied, a pointer that pointed to the original object, a reference that referred to the original object, or the name of the original object will automatically refer to the new object and, once the lifetime of the new object has started, can be used to manipulate the new object _[..]_

Comment: So I guess weird as it looks, it's perfectly well-defined except the "wrong" destructor is called in the edited code snippet now. But I guess this doesn't matter since the premise was "do not rely on what the destructor does". So there cannot be any resources that need to be freed in the destructor.

Comment: @Damon: It's not the "wrong" destructor. I'm safely destroying the second object. But the point here is that failing to destroy the first did not result in UB!

Comment: In short: you may just scrap the first object without actually *destroying* it if and only if the program does not rely on any side effects of its destruction.

Comment: +1 Wow, this is just mind boggling. I would've sworn this is UB if you'd asked me. So much for thinking I know C++! But what does it even mean to "rely on the side effects" of a destructor? If I increment a global counter in the destructor and print that counter, am I "relying" on it even if I don't particularly care what the value is? What if I instead print the XOR of that counter with a random number? Maybe I should ask this as a separate question...

Comment: @Mehrdad Indeed, I don't think anybody knows 